# Android. Positioning of the elements in relativelayot

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `RelativeLayout` with `CardView`, 
inside which are placed: `ImageView`, `TextView1`, `TextView2`. 
These 3 elements needed to place so `ImageView` 
must be left, `TextView1` and `TextView2` 
to the right of it. `TextView2` must be pressed to the bottom of `CardView`, 
at the same time be below of `TextView1` (if `TextView1` has much text). 
Now there are no questions about the first two elements, 
but there are problems with 3 (second `TextView`): 
or it is pressed to the bottom, but it is overlaped by the first `TextView`(if the first `TextView` has much text), or it is below of `TextView1`, but it is not pressed to the bottom. Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorBackground">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_view_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_photo"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/news_card_view_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_card_view_height"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/news_card_view_photo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/news_photo"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news_photo"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_date"
                android:textColor="@color/text_labels"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/news_title"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news_photo"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/news_photo"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

What i want to do:

[image]

Comment: What does your current view looks like ?

Comment: In my current view i see image, firt and second TextViews, but second TextView is overlaped by first, and they are displayed like one item.

Comment: Yeah, great solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `android:gravity="bottom"` to `news_date` `TextView`.

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_date"
                android:textColor="@color/text_labels"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/news_title"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news_photo"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/news_photo"
                android:gravity="bottom"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a LinearLayout instead. Have a horizontal LinearLayout with your ImageView and a vertical LinearLayout containing TextView1 and TextView 2.

Then, in the inner LinearLayout add a View (filler) with a weight of 1 and a height of 0dp after TextView1 to push TextView2 to the bottom. Or set a weight for each (TextView1, View and TextView2) to set the height proportions appropriately. See below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vertical_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/filler"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```